# Partial derivative deduction.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Calculate $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}$ and deduce $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}$

I've done the calculations for $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}$ and got $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}$=$\frac{x^4y+4x^2y^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

However i have no idea how to deduce $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}$.

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One word: symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint...note that $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ so you should just get the negative of the same expression but with the $x$ and the $y$ interchanged.

Comment: I'm failing to see what happens when $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ , the only case I know is when $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ then the partial derivative with respect to $y$ can be found by interchanging x and y.I'd appreciate it if you could explain further or link me to somewhere where this case is stated.

Comment: If you exchange $x$ for $y$ throughout you get the same as the negative of the original function. So differentiating partially w.r.t $y$ instead is going to give the same expression, but negative.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have clarified my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will get $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{y \left(x^4+4 x^2
   y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{x \left(x^4-4 x^2
   y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$